Decompose a quantum circuit into basis gates
I am not able to understand how to decompose the quantum circuit into the basis gates.
I tried the below code in the latest version of qiskit==1.0 but I realize this approach is not correct.
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import UCRYGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import  FakeKolkata
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
import math
import pdb
num_qubits = 3
data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
])
angles = [np.pi / 4, np.pi / 2, 3 * np.pi / 4, np.pi]
controls = [0, 1]
target = [2]

qr1 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name= 'q')
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(qr1)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)

qr2 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name='q')
qc2= QuantumCircuit(qr2)

qc2.unitary(data, qr2, label= 'u')

qc1 = qc1.compose(qc2, list(range(0, num_qubits)))
qc1 = qc1.decompose()  # Decomposing the quantum circuit
print(qc1.draw())

When I print the circuit, it looks like as below:

It would be really kind help if someone can guide me on this because this circuit kind of gates are definitely not basis gates.
Edit1 Decompose removed, transpile added, but it really donot break down the circuit into basis gates or native gates.
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import UCRYGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import  FakeKolkata
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
import math
import pdb
num_qubits = 3
data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
])
angles = [np.pi / 4, np.pi / 2, 3 * np.pi / 4, np.pi]
controls = [0, 1]
target = [2]

qr1 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name= 'q')
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(qr1)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)

qr2 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name='q')
qc2= QuantumCircuit(qr2)

qc2.unitary(data, qr2, label= 'u')

qc1 = qc1.compose(qc2, list(range(0, num_qubits)))


qc1.measure_all()

shots_used = 10000
print("Circuit depth: ", qc2.depth())
print("Circuit gate counts:", qc2.count_ops())

backend = AerSimulator()
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=3)
qc_optimized = pm.run(qc1)

print("Optimzied circuit depth: ", qc_optimized.depth())
print("Optimized gate counts:", qc_optimized.count_ops())

print(qc_optimized.draw())  # drawing ckt after transpile
pdb.set_trace()
job = backend.run(qc_optimized, shots = shots_used)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(qc_optimized)



Which set of basis gates were you expecting?

Thank you the response @EthanDavies. I expect some gates like CNOT gates, Ry, Rz, Rx, H, X, control Rx, control Ry, control Rz gates, basically the well defined gates we find in text books.

The decompose function only exposes the construction layer below of some given circuit or gate implementation. It has nothing to do with the basis gates of a particular backend. Although, in some given library, a lot of the gates might be constructed out of components of a popular gate-set.
In any case, to transform a circuit to a basis set, you need to transpile it by giving the transpiler information about which gate set you want to use.
Here’s an analogy using classical circuits. Imagine you have a library that has a circuit for a full adder. You decide to “decompose$^*$” the circuit and find out that it is made out of AND, OR and NOT gates. That’s all well and good, but it is not giving you information about the actual type transistors that will be used to implement that in a specific chip. You would then need to “transpile$^*$” your circuit to a specific technology node (let’s say TSMC CMOS 65 nm) to match the hardware where that circuit will be implemented.
$^*$Decompose and transpile and not words typically used in digital circuit design. Just using them here for the purpose of this analogy.
Answer to Edit1
You transpiled your circuit using AerSimulator as the backend. All of the gates shown in the circuit diagram you shared are part of the basis gates of the AerSimulator.
You can find the list of supported operations by running:
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
print(AerSimulator().operation_names)

which will give you this as an output:
['y', 'for_loop', 'cu', 'continue_loop', 'sx', 'save_matrix_product_state', 'cx', 'mcy', 'save_clifford', 'mcx_gray', 'save_statevector_dict', 'if_else', 'quantum_channel', 'initialize', 'save_expval_var', 'set_superop', 'set_stabilizer', 'reset', 'mcu1', 'crx', 'superop', 'mcsx', 'multiplexer', 'tdg', 'u2', 'mcx', 'switch_case', 'cy', 'z', 'csx', 'mcu', 'mcp', 'save_statevector', 'break_loop', 'rx', 'ccz', 'set_unitary', 'p', 'rzz', 'ry', 'swap', 'measure', 's', 'rxx', 'u', 'unitary', 'mcrz', 'mcz', 'cu3', 'rz', 'cu2', 'pauli', 'set_density_matrix', 'set_statevector', 'id', 'mcu3', 'mcswap', 'save_state', 'cry', 'cu1', 'save_density_matrix', 'save_unitary', 'cp', 'save_stabilizer', 'qerror_loc', 'sdg', 'ecr', 't', 'r', 'mcphase', 'u3', 'ryy', 'h', 'kraus', 'x', 'ccx', 'sxdg', 'u1', 'save_amplitudes', 'delay', 'mcr', 'mcry', 'crz', 'mcu2', 'roerror', 'mcrx', 'save_expval', 'save_superop', 'while_loop', 'set_matrix_product_state', 'rzx', 'cz', 'save_probabilities_dict', 'diagonal', 'save_amplitudes_sq', 'save_probabilities', 'cswap']

If you were to do this for a different backend, you will get a different outcome. For example:
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeKolkataV2
print(FakeKolkataV2().operation_names)

results in the list of the gates are are supported by that particular fake QPU:
['cx', 'x', 'reset', 'measure', 'rz', 'delay', 'sx', 'id']


I also always though the transpile or generate_preset_pass_manager into basis gates but it really donot do that. I have edited the question. Please review.

It did. You used the AerSimulator as your backend to perform the transpilation process and all of the gates shown in the image are part of that simulator's gate set. For a different gate set, you need to pass as the backend whichever QPU or FakeProvider you want to use in that particular instance.

Also, I want to comment that it is very common for you to ask one question, get a fairly accurate answer, and then modify your question to something else. Please be more conscientious when you ask your questions from the get-go because they end up being a back-and-forth discussion of different subjects, which is not what StackExchange is designed for.

Thank you @diemilio for the response. So every simulator, fake HW, real HW have a gate set.  The transpiler will break the quantum circuit into some circuit using those gates. Decompose function will decompose the given circuit into some circuit but there is no well defined documentation for that.

@Manu, correct.

Thank you @diemilio for great help.
